# Silverstripe :: Multiple sitetree

Tags: silverstripe

we are in the process of re-structuring our site. We have a lot of pages (a lot) spanning 5 levels deep. Our new UX designer is trying to sort this out. As part of this she is proposing this page/content restructure (this re-structure is going to take atleast 6 weeks). The organization cant afford to have the site frozen for 6 weeks. So my questions are

1. Is there any simplified way of modifying the structure of the site without affecting the production site...how to handle this
2. Can we create a copy of existing sitetree (i.e have multiple sitetrees, one active and one in draft state) and do the changes there? Once we are ready, can we switch? (just a thought)
3. Ideas please

Cheers
RD

Answer (score 1):

1) Will "the process of re-structuring" involve coding work? Why not just copy db and code to another host instance (say staging.yourdomain.com) and do your enhancements there? (any changes there will not affect the current site).

Actually, in most development environments, there are usually at least two versions of the site running where one is for testing/staging site and 
changes are approved there by the customer before going live.

It is not a good practice to create many unused pages or play on the 
production site.

2) You want to have two copies of the Site Tree on the production instance? Well, you can sortof do it using silverstripe-copybutton module and it will make an exact copy of the page.

But is not a good thing to do. You will need to delete a lot of things later and your database may grow as Site Tree is a versioned object and it will remember previous revisions. Additionally, if some coding work is also required, you can't really do it on the production site as it will affect the pages visible to visitors.

However, if the change is only related to the page content and you can't afford to have a separate instance of the site, you can use copy module to copy a page and make the changes in the copied version and then replace the old one with new one.

This is not a recommended way and you have to be very careful. If you hard delete any dependency like another object or image used by one page, it will be removed from the original version as well because the target object doesnt exist anymore.

3) see above

Answer (score 1):

1)Moving pages in SilverStripe doesn't effect the production site, assuming that you are meaning the "live" site when you say this.

2) When you move a page in SilverStripe it is seen as a "draft" change and does not take effect on the "live" site until approved and published. So basically SilverStripe already works the way you want/need it to as the "live" and "draft" state in SilverStripe is already like 2 different sitetrees. There are some other things to consider though. If you also need/want to change content during the process a pages restructure will go live when you save and publish the content changes. If you do a complete restructure you can make everything live through batch action.

3)SilverStripe Australia built the external content module and subsequent connectors for integration and content migration. There is a SilverStripe to SilverStripe connector that provides the ability to connect another instance to the current system and have it's sitetree represented in the admin interface of the new system. You can then selectively move the site into a new structure in the new system.

https://github.com/silverstripe-australia/silverstripe-connector